# Symfony 4, when I try to submit a form it does not work

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Thanks in advance to those who want to help me. I'm learning symfony 4 and I'm testing to see how to update a database by taking data from a form. So I made sure that it looked for a table on the base of the id and that it filled the form with the correct values ​​of the form. But when I submit, the form-> isSubmitted condition is never verified. Do you have any suggestions?

```
    public function updateArticle(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->getRepository(Article::class)->find($id);
    if (!$article) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No article found for id '.$id
        );
    }
    $articletext = $article->getArticle();
    $title = $article->getTitle();
    $image = $article->getFeatureimage();
    $category = $article->getCategory();
    $author = $article->getAuthor();
    $article->setArticle($articletext);
    $article->setTitle($title);
    $article->setFeatureimage($image);
    $article->setCategory($category);
    $article->setAuthor($author);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($article)
        ->add('article', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('featureimage', FileType::class, array('data_class' => null,'required' => true))
        ->add('category', TextType::class)
        ->add('author', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Inserisci articolo'))
        ->getForm();
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $article = $form->getData();
        print_r($article);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog');
      }
      else
        return $this->render('insert.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your forgot a line that handle the data.
[Look at the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)
Add this line before the if condition:

```
//form creation as you did but it's better to construct the form via the FormType

$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted()){
//Do some stuff
```

Comment: You should also test if the form is valid.
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {}

Comment: Great! Thank you!